# Stacking multiclass classification accuracy is lower than same model for binary classification problem?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification, ensemble-learning

I have developed a stacked classification model which consists of Random forest, CNN, and logistic regression as a meta-model. Its accuracy is 99% for binary classification problem and its accuracy on multiclass classification is very low.

```
Epoch 1/50
11527/11527 - 172s - loss: 0.4597 - accuracy: 0.0560
Epoch 2/50
11527/11527 - 153s - loss: 0.2507 - accuracy: 0.0486
Epoch 3/50
11527/11527 - 125s - loss: 0.1830 - accuracy: 0.0442
Epoch 4/50
11527/11527 - 118s - loss: 0.1447 - accuracy: 0.0442
Epoch 5/50
11527/11527 - 96s - loss: 0.1220 - accuracy: 0.0440
```

I am using Keras APIs kerasClassifer and stackingClassifier and also used softmax activation for output in the CNN model.
What is the problem with model?